# Partial match not working for phone number field using searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

When the query is specified as given below i.e provided with the exact match then searchkick gives the result.

> User.search("9898989898", fields: [{first_name: :word_start},
>   :middle_name, :last_name, :phone_number])

But when partial query is provided i.e without exact match then no search result is obtained.

> User.search("9898", fields: [{first_name: :word_start}, :middle_name,
>   :last_name, :phone_number]) This query does not give any result.

Note: The query can be string for first_name, middle_name and last_name whereas numeric for phone_number

Does anyone have idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want partial match for the phone number field as well as first_name you need to provide the word_start for both the fields. You may try this:

```
User.search("9898", fields: [{first_name: :word_start}, :middle_name, :last_name, {phone_number: :word_start}]).
```

And also in the User model please put both the fields
    searchkick word_start: [:first_name, :phone_number]